# Launch IE with a switch from a COM object (PowerShell)

Tags: internet-explorer, powershell, comobject, com-object, lockdown

I need to do two things. One is to launch IE hidden until I've locked down certain elements such as hiding the address bar and the second is to launch it with the -noframemerging switch. This is help with delivering web related App-V packages in a Citrix environment.

I'm aware that Group Policy can be used to achieve the lockdown, but the environment where IE is being launched needs the lockdowns set per instance of IE, not as a blanket setting across all.

I have used New-Object -ComObject InternetExplorer.Application to create an IE COM Object in PowerShell and set various properties to create a locked down environment and I can get IE to launch be changing the visible property.

This however launches an instance of iexplore.exe without any switches. Is it possible to launch IE with the -noframemerging switch using this COM object as a template?

Any help would be appreciated.

Cheers,

Matt

Comment: Looks like a duplicate of [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18317902/powershell-com-object-with-parameters).

Comment: It does indeed.I have seen this post and tried it. The problem is that IE actually displays briefly using this method and this some thing that I am trying to avoid. With a COM Object I can at least set up the browser first without it displaying.

Comment: Have you tried [this](https://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/windowsserver/en-US/af2cdf98-5279-4f13-a922-139823adbaa2/open-ie-9-via-powershell-with-noframemerging?forum=winserverpowershell)?

Comment: Yes. Whilst the title includes noframemerging, there does not appear to be any information about how to include the switch. The code posted is essentially the same code I am using to create the COM object. Of course raising the code in this manner may have the same effect, but the post doesn't appear to confirm or deny this.